# What is the difference between assign and return?

Tags: javascript

I think I'm too stupid to understand the difference between:

1.

```
var a, b;
a = 1;
b = a;
console.log(b); // 1
```

2.

```
var x, y;
x = 2;
y = function (z) {
  return z;
}
console.log(y(x)); // 2
```

I just can't understand. Is this matter the data is a Number or an Array/Object?

Thanks.

Comment: An assignment assigns a value to variable. A return statement returns a value from a function. They are two different operations with different purposes. The data type of the value is irrelevant. This is also not specific to JavaScript, these operations exist in most programming languages. Maybe if you can elaborate on what exactly confuses you we can help you better.

Comment: Well, actually I have an additional question. Like, why in one way: 1: var a = Array.from(arraylike).length - it will return 15, for example and for another way (es6): 2. var a = () => Array.from(arraylike).length - it will return "undefined" ? Why this happens?

Comment: That's not a complete example so I can't answer that question. And comments aren't for new questions. Maybe you just need to spend some time reading a JavaScript tutorial such as http://eloquentjavascript.net/ .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assignment operations and returning values out of functions are two separate things.

A lot of programming can be thought of as moving *values* from one place to another.

*Assignment* is taking a value from one place and storing it in another. In your code, for instance:

```
a = 1;
```

the expression on the right-hand side (`1`) is evaluated, and the resulting value (`1`) is stored in `a`. (Yes, `1` is an expression; in this case, it's a literal expression that gives us the value `1`.) Similarly:

```
b = a;
```

the expression on the right-hand side (`a`) is evaluated, and the resulting value (`1`) is stored in `b`.

*Returning* something does two things (in JavaScript and most — but not all — other languages)

1. It evaluates the expression after the `return` keyword, and then sets the resulting value as the *return value* of the function.
2. It ends the function, returning back to the point where the function was called.

With functions, what we do most of the time (all of the time in JavaScript) is pass values *into* the function, let the function do things with those values, and then have the function give us back a value (the *result* of calling the function).

In your:

```
var x, y;
x = 2;
y = function (z) {
  return z;
}
console.log(y(x)); // 2
```

we already know how `x = 2` works (see `a = 1` above). Then we do:

```
y = function (z) {
  return z;
}
```

and, as always, the right-hand side expression (`function(z) { return z; }`) is evaluated, which creates a function object, and then the resulting value of that (the reference* to the function) is stored in `y`.

So far so good.

Now:

```
console.log(y(2)); // 2
```

There, we're doing this:

- Evaluating the innermost expression (`2`), and getting its resulting value (`2`)
- *Calling* `y` and passing that value into it
- Inside `y`, it receives the value in its `z` parameter, almost like you'd reached into the function and put the value into a variable called `z` inside the function
- Then we do `return z`, which evaluates the expression after the `return` (`z`), and then terminates the function, returning the resulting value (`2` in this case)
- The result of calling `y` is therefore the value `2`
- The whole process happens again with `console.log`, which uses its parameter to output the value `2` to the console

---

* "reference" - In JavaScript and most (but not all) other programming languages, we don't actually copy objects around; instead, we pass arounda  value called an *object reference*, which is basically something that tells the language runtime where the object is in memory (like a street address says where your house is). Objects aren't values, but object *references* are values. Since functions in JavaScript are objects, `y = function() { }` creates a function and then stores the reference to it in `y`.

Comment: Impressive reply. Thanks a lot. I think I need some time to understand it fully.

Comment: Well, actually I have an additional question. Like, why in one way:
1: var a = Array.from(arraylike).length - it will return 15, for example
and for another way (es6):
2. var a = () => Array.from(arraylike).length - it will return "undefined" ?
Why this happens?

Comment: @almazmusic: It won't, but those are two very different expressions. In the first one, you're calling `Array.from`, getting the `length` from its result, and then storing that value in `a`. In the second one, you're *creating* a function and storing its reference in `a`. (Later, if you call that function -- `a()` -- it will return the result of doing `Array.from(arraylike).length` as of when you call it.)

Answer (score 1):

Assignment operators assign values to JavaScript variables.
`return` stops function execution and returns a value from it, you can "assign" that value using the `=` sign or discard it

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_assignment.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_return.asp